# Reference for this verse - heta irṣyeta phale na tu

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, reference-request, shloka

Hi all trying to find the reference of this shloka:

> heta irṣyeta phale na tu

> हेता ईर्ष्येत फले न तू

it roughly translates to Envy for the cause/reason of someone success is not bad and does not result in any karma.

Comment: It is from Śukranīti 3.9-10. (https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.540296/page/n110/mode/1up?view=theater)